# How do I group the Find results of Single Table Inheritance Sub Class of a Sub Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, single-table-inheritance

I have a three STI classes.

```
class Media < ActiveRecord::Base

end

class Music < Media

end


class CD < Music

end
```

1. When I do a Media.all => I get objects from the music class and CD class.
2. But, when I do Music.all => I only get objects from the Music class.

I would like the Music.all to return objects from both Music and CD classes.  Is this possible and how do I achieve it.  I've been googling most of the afternoon, but have not come across anything that helps me achieve my objective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Single Table Inheritance (STI): HOWTO scope records of inherited model?**

**Solution 1:** The way that ActiveRecord developers have provided but for some reason it doesn't work by default for years! [why?]

```
class Media < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end

class Music < Media
  def self.descendants
    super|[CD]
  end
end

class CD < Music
  ...
end

# Result:

Music.where(:name => "Pink Floyd").to_sql
#=> SELECT "medias".* FROM "medias" WHERE "medias"."type" IN ('Music', 'CD') AND "medias"."name" = "Pink Floyd"
```

**Solution 2:** customize 'STI' type condition directly:

```
class Music < Media
  private
  def self.type_condition(*args)
    super.tap {|arel_node| arel_node.right << "CD"}
  end
end
```

Comment: Would you mind walking me through your response.  It's way out of my league.  Many thanks.

Comment: This is a little trick. Generally speaking, we override the key method of AR's inheritance logic that determines basic parameters for scoping STI's db table. We've just learned him how to look for other classes. The solution was found as elegant as harmless.

Comment: "The way that ActiveRecord developers have provided" can you link to where you found this?

Comment: Line 154 https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/de1b687239832f336b9453493701955ab4d6d6a2/activerecord/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb

Comment: As you see, according to a source code every parent model should include descendant models for scoping. But somehow it does not. Because the method `descendants` works is still not predictable, and even in the head branch (almost Rails 4.0)...

Comment: Thanks for this; it's a file I should have read a long time ago (I use STI quite a bit and there's a lot of great knowledge here)

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do is override the `all` method in the `Music` class.

```
def self.all
  super + CD.all
end
```

`+` will concatenate all `CD` instances to the result set array of all `Music` instances.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Will this also allow me use Music.last so that it returns the last from music or cd.